# NG-REPEAT dentro de NG-REPEAT - ANGULARJS

Tags: angularjs, array, array-multidimensional, ng-repeat

Possuo um array multidimensional.

Para demonstrá-lo em minha view utilizo um ng-repeat em um ul dentro de um outro ng-repeat em um li, desta forma:

```
<ul ng-repeat="section in sections">
  <li>
      {{section.name}}
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials">
          {{tutorial.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

De que forma eu poderia demonstrar esses valores em uma tabela? 
Sendo que não é possível desta forma:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <tr ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials"> 
      <td>{{:: tutorial.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver utilizando o ng-repeat-start e ng-repeat-end. Segue:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <td ng-repeat-start="tutorial in section.tutorials">{{:: tutorial.name }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat-end>{{:: tutorial.autor }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

tente isso

```
<tr ng-repeat="tutorial  in tutorials| filterData: 'sections'">
   <td>{{tutorial.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

ou use tbody

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="section in sections">
  <tr ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials">
    <td>{{:: tutorial.name }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Não deu certo de nenhuma das formas :(

Comment: Poderia postar suas estrutura json do objeto sections?

Comment: Consegui! haha, vou postar aqui..